# Using AWK to select records from file1 with obs.# in file 2

Tags: select, awk, extract

I have these to simple test files:
This is fil1, containing records I want to select some from
01
02
07
05
10
20
30
25

This is keepNR, containing the record numbers I want to extract from fil1
1
4
7

What I want are these records from fil1
01    (observation/record # 1)
05    (observation/record # 4)
30    (observation/record # 7)

I am a novice to AWK, but I have tried these programs:

using this, I can see that the observations are there
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next } { for (elem in a) {  print "elem=",elem,"FNR=",FNR,"$1=",$1 }}  '  keepNR fil1

I had hoped this would work, but I get more than the 2 records:

awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next } { for (elem in a) { if (FNR ~ a[elem]) print elem,FNR,$1; next }}  END{  for (elem in a) {  print "END:", elem }}'  keepNR fil1
1 1 01
1 2 02
1 3 07
1 4 05
1 5 10
1 6 20
1 7 30
1 8 25

I first tried using the == instead of the ~, but then no result ??
as you can see here:

gg@gg:~/bin/awktest$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next } { for (elem in a) { if (FNR == a[elem]) print elem,FNR,$1; next }}  '  keepNR fil1
gg@gg:~/bin/awktest$

I have also tried (FNR - a[elem])==0 with no output

So I have 2 questions

1. why does if (FNR ~ a[elem]) work, but if (FNR == a[elem]) does not ?
2. why do I get 8 lines of output, instead of 2 ?

If you have a better solution, I would love to see it

Kind Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign to `a[$1]` so its **value** is empty:  `FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }`

`for (elem in a)` sets `elem` to the **keys** of `a`.

`if (FNR == a[elem])` compares against the **value** in `a[elem]`. The value is empty, so there is no match.

`if (FNR ~ a[elem])` tests if `FNR` matches the empty regex (`//`), so it always matches.

---

A simpler method is to test if `FNR` is a **key** of `a`:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
    FNR in a { print "FNR="FNR, "$1="$1 }
' keepNR fil1
```

which should output:

```
FNR=1 $1=01
FNR=4 $1=05
FNR=7 $1=30
```

Comment: Hi jhnc : THANK YOU very much ! Your awk code is much easier than mine . I have also gotten my code to work by assigning a[$1]=$1 like this  awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1; next } { for (elem in a) { if (FNR == a[elem]) print elem,$1 }}  '  keepNR fil1 once again thank you:)

Comment: @Golem don't use the code in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946645/using-awk-to-select-records-from-file1-with-obs-in-file-2#comment120098382_67947676). Just **think** about what your code does - it really doesn't make any sense and it'll be far slower and use far more memory than the script jhnc provided.

Comment: Hi Ed  that was my intention all the time, but I wanted to see if my code worked with the change